# spresenseのブートローダーの書き込みができない

Tags: spresense

公式のスタートガイドに従ってインストールしてみるもブートローダーの書き込みができない。長々と書き込み中の表示が出て30分くらいしてようやく書き込み中にエラーが発生しましたと出て終わり。
どこが間違っているのか、何が原因なのか教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USBシリアルドライバーが最新のだとうまくいかないケースもあるようです。
そこはどうでしょうか？

[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_usb_ドライバのインストール](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_usb_%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%90%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

Comment: もともと所持していボードは引き出しの中に眠っていたもので保存状態が悪かったのか動きませんでした。そこで新しい基盤を買って試したらブートローダの書き込みができました。おそらく基盤自体の問題かと思われます。